# Matlab divergence of a randomly sampled 3d vector field

Tags: matlab, vector, octave

I am trying to use the `divergence` function in Matlab over a dataset which is not ordered. I have therefore the x, y, z positions of the origins of the vectors (3 columns) and the three components Fx, Fy, Fz of the vector field (3 columns), for a total of a 6 columns dataset, where the positions are random points in a 3d volume. How should I transform the data in order to be readable by `divergence`?

I guess I should use `meshgrid` and generate an ordered grid associated to my original random points, but how should I deal with the vector field F?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, use a meshgrid to generate the uniform datapoints, and then if your data is well behaved, you should be able to interpolate using interp3.

```
FinterpX = interp3(Xmeas,Ymeas,Zmeas,FmeasX,Xgrid, Ygrid, Zgrid);
FinterpY = interp3(Xmeas,Ymeas,Zmeas,FmeasY,Xgrid, Ygrid, Zgrid);
FinterpZ = interp3(Xmeas,Ymeas,Zmeas,FmeasZ,Xgrid, Ygrid, Zgrid);
```

However, your random datapoints may not work well with this approach, due to the constraints that interp3 puts on them.

Comment: I have tried, but it seems that I am missing something basic: Fmeas has to be a 3d array, while for me it is just a 2d array with three columns and a certain number M of rows. Moreover, Xmeas, Ymeas... and Xgrid, Ygrid... have to be of the same dimensions, which clearly are not since one is the measured data and the other are the interpolation points. Any suggestion on how to reshape the data?

Comment: Yes, I realize that this doesn't work now.  It will work if you separate Fmeas into its components and do a separate interp for each one.  I will make this change.  Xmeas, Ymeas, and Zmeas can be vectors.

Comment: I take that back.  After reading the documentation for interp3, I am now more confused.  I am not sure if it is possible to structure Xmeas, Ymeas, and Zmeas for your problem.  If they are vectors, then they must be strictly monotonic increasing, which is impossible if you want to fill a 3D space.  Sorry, I will think about this more.